# Jquery fadeout function redraws old image

Tags: jquery

I am using this function to fadeout the old image on click  and then fade in new image

```
$("#left_img img").fadeOut(1000, function() {

    $(this).attr("src","/image/p2r.gif").fadeIn(500);

});
```

The problem is when first image is faded out then before the new image fades in , the first image loads again for 1 second and then new image fades in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the image hasn't fully loaded, try adding an event listener to it to fade it in once it's loaded, like so:

```
$("#left_img img").fadeOut(1000, function() {

    $(this).attr("src","/image/p2r.gif").load( function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

Edit: My apologies, that should be "load" instead of "ready." Not to be confused with the `load()` function for AJAX.

Comment: When you set the src to a different image, the image must be loaded; while it's loading the old image is still displayed. This adds an event listener for when the image has finished loading.